# react i18next throws translator missingKey en translation and useTranslation() hooks not working

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I am setting up the [react-i18n-next](https://react.i18next.com/latest/usetranslation-hook)  hook to translate my app and i followed the example that the react-i18n-next use but it throws error like below:

```
i18next::translator: missingKey
en-US
translation
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component, Suspense } from "react";
import { useTranslation, withTranslation, Trans } from "react-i18next";

// use hoc for class based components
class LegacyWelcomeClass extends Component {
  render() {
    const { t } = this.props;
    return <h2>{t("title")}</h2>;
  }
}
const Welcome = withTranslation()(LegacyWelcomeClass);

// Component using the Trans component
function MyComponent() {
  return <Trans i18nKey="description.part1" />;
}

// page uses the hook
function Page() {
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();

  const changeLanguage = lng => {
    i18n.changeLanguage(lng);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="App-header">
        <Welcome />
        <button type="button" onClick={() => changeLanguage("de")}>
          de
        </button>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => changeLanguage("en")}>
          en
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="App-intro">
        <MyComponent />
      </div>
      <div>{t("description.part2")}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

// loading component for suspense fallback
const Loader = () => (
  <div className="App">
    <div>loading...</div>
  </div>
);

// here app catches the suspense from page in case translations are not yet loaded
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
      <Page />
    </Suspense>
  );
}
```

i18n.js

```
import i18n from "i18next";
import Backend from "i18next-http-backend";
import LanguageDetector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";

i18n
  .use(Backend)

  .use(LanguageDetector)

  .use(initReactI18next)

  .init({
    fallbackLng: "en",
    debug: true,

    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false // not needed for react as it escapes by default
    }
  });

export default i18n;
```

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

// import i18n (needs to be bundled ;))
import "./i18n";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

sample code available [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-htxvxy?file=src/index.js) and I don't know what I am missing, It would be better to get some basic working example,s and any help on this really helpful.

**My requirement is, I need to translate my app to some other language like from en to fr, the only context I have is en file.**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are certain things you need to do in the above code

1. First of all you need to make two translation files, in which you are missing some keys and their values.

let suppose translationEN.json -

```
{
  "title": "Title",
  "Welcome to React": "Welcome to React and react-i18next",
  "description": {
    "part2": "some description"
  }
}
```

and translationDE.json -

```
{
  "title": "DE ***** Title",
  "Welcome to React": "DE  **** Welcome to React and react-i18next",
  "description": {
    "part2": "DE  **** some description"
  }
}
```

2. Import the above files in i18n.js and Add **resources** and **lng** in i18n init

   ```
    import translationEN from "../src/translationEN.json";
    import translationDE from "../src/translationDE.json";

    const resources = {
      en: {
        translation: translationEN
      },
      de: {
        translation: translationDE
      }
    };

    i18n
     .use(Backend)    
     .use(LanguageDetector)    
     .use(initReactI18next)    
     .init({
      resources,
      lng: "en",
   ```

Solution is added [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ybzhyk)

Comment: The solution is showing loading.. not the desired output can you check it once

Comment: The solution worked but my requirement is I have en json and I want to convert it some other language ,. example english to french but how do i know the fr json . Example hello world in english needs to be converted to french like Bonjour le monde

Comment: add your translated strings in their translation files with keeping the same keys in JSON, only change their values

Comment: my doubt is that how do I get that translated strings, isn't that react-i18n should do? https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-swfmbf?file=src/translationDE.json in this json I have to put the hello world translated string- Is that what you're expecting?

Comment: @user0227 react-i18n just will help you to choose what files should be presented whenever you select any language. It won't translate anything automatically, you need to do that manually for each and individual string of your project. This is what actual language localization is in i18n.